# How can I load 2 random pages?

Tags: page-template, homepage

My problem is quite simple: I want to show a different page each time a visitor comes to my page. There are 2 pages for now, but it could be more. I have found this code:

```
$rand = rand(1,2);

switch($rand){

    case 1:
        get_template_part('template1');
    break;

    case 2:
        get_template_part('template2');
    break;       
}
```

but I don't want template parts, I really need to make it go through 2 (or more) complete pages I can define by URL or slug. Or it could be posts as well, as long as I can make them completely different (this is for multivariate testing of completely different pages which include some user interaction I want to measure)

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Note that it will be impossible to cache this page as a result unless you do the loading in javascript on the clientside, rather than on the server. Also note that anything involving random and the database will be excessively expensive/slow

Comment: @TomJNowell, cache is not an issue. As a matter of fact I didn't know that, but what you say is kind of an added benefit, I need to avoid cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect users from home page to random page with this code (paste it to your functions.php)

```
function my_homepage_redirect() {
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
        $page = get_posts( [
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category' => 1, // your category ID
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'fields' => 'ids'
        ] );

        if ( empty( $page ) ){
            return;
        }

        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $page[0] ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_homepage_redirect' );
```

If you want to pick random page OR random post, you can modify the 'post_type' parameter:
`'post_type' => [ 'post', 'page' ],`

Comment: thank you Levi. The problem is that it cycles through all existing pages, including those I'm not testing. Is is possible to limit this to only 2 pages? or it could be posts, maybe in a category

Comment: Sure, you can limit posts to a category, I've edited my answet above (the line with `'category' => 1 // your category ID`, also change `'post_type'` to **'post'** in that case